# Cutting mp4 files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

The rule for cutting a mp4 file with ffmpeg is quite simple if the cut point is a keyframe and the input file only contains I and P frames:

- with -ss the output file will start with the keyframe
- with -to or -t it will end with the frame before the keyframe.

If the input file also contains B-frames, the first statement remains true but it seems that two frames follow the expected last frame: the keyframe and the next P-frame (when some B-frames follow the keyframe, those B-frames are skipped).

Notice that if you decrement the cut point of 0.080 second (if framerate=25), the output file will end before the keyframe.

I don't understand why, can someone explain to me why?
[This is my first post on stackoverflow]

Comment: I have added the sentence about the skipped B-frames to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

When cutting a video file with ffmpeg, the keyframe is an important factor in determining where the cut should be made. Keyframes are frames that contain complete image information and are used as reference points by video codecs to reconstruct the video.

When using the "-ss" option to specify the start point of the output file, ffmpeg will look for the closest keyframe before the specified time and start the output file from that point.

When using the "-to" or "-t" option to specify the end point of the output file, ffmpeg will stop the output file at the closest keyframe before the specified time. If there is no keyframe before the specified time, ffmpeg will use the next keyframe after the specified time as the end point and add a few frames after the last expected frame.

This behavior occurs when the input file contains B-frames. B-frames are bidirectional frames that depend on both previous and future frames for their compression. Due to this dependence, B-frames cannot be used as reference points for reconstructing the video and therefore cannot be used as keyframes.

When cutting a video that contains B-frames, ffmpeg will still use the closest keyframe as the starting point of the output file, but when determining the end point, ffmpeg may have to use a B-frame as the last frame before the next keyframe. This is because the next keyframe may be far away, and ffmpeg wants to avoid truncating any frames before the next keyframe, which could result in visual artifacts or other issues.

In summary, when cutting a video file with ffmpeg, the use of keyframes is important in determining the start and end points of the output file. If the input file contains B-frames, ffmpeg may use a B-frame as the last frame before the next keyframe to avoid truncating any frames

Comment: Sorry, but that do not explain why "ffmpeg -to" EXcludes the keyframe when B-frames are absent and INclude the keyframe (and a P-frame !) when B-frames are present in the input file.